# External css file wont load when opening my webpage

Tags: html, css, tomcat

I'm building a website with eclipse / tomcat. In my html file I've included an external css file.
When i open my main website page as a file, everything is working fine and it reads the external css file , But when i try to open the main page using tomcat:   "MyHost:8080/DBankOnline/MainPage.html" It loads the html but doesn't load the external css file.
Why won't it load the external css when trying to open my website from MyHost ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"               "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="DBankwebsite30.css" type="text/css">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1255">
<title>DBank - The best bank</title>
</head>

<script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="mainScript17.js"></script>
<style>

#content>p
{
font-size:20px;
font-style:italic;
}
</style>

<body onload="javascript:setInterval(clock,1000);javascript:buttonClicked();">
<div id="main">
<div id="upper">
    <p id="welcomeMessage">Hello guest.</p>
    <div id="login">
        <a href="loginpage.html">&nbsp; &nbsp; Login/Logout</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="left">
<div id="hour"></div>
    <ul>
        <li id="MainPage" class="mainButtons"><a href="MainPage.html">- Home -</a><hr></li>
        <li id="Personal" class="mainButtons"><a href="Personal.html">- Personal -</a><hr></li>
        <li id="AboutUs" class="mainButtons"><a href="localHost:8080/MainPage/AboutUsButton.html">- About us -</a><hr></li>
        <li id="ContactUs" class="mainButtons"><a href="localHost:8080/MainPage/ContactUsButton.html">- Contact us -</a><hr></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="content">
    <p> Hello universe </p>

</div>

<div id="bottom"> 
    <p id="rights">The best website</p>
</div>
```

-thank you

Comment: Go to your package explorer and refresh.

Comment: Probably a path issue... look into how Tomcat interprets paths

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely a path issue.
Use chrome browser to inspect elements and see which path your external css file is used by the host then you have a clue. I ran into similar cases before. Not a big issue. Good luck.